# How to use excel ranges in excel vba formulas

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel VBA I get syntax error messages when I try option 1 and option 2.

How do I set ranges correctly so that I can use my formula in option 1?

For Option 2, why can't I refer to the ranges just like in normal excel formulas?

This is because I wanted to apply this formula to many rows below this cell. Do I use for loop?

The default code is correct.

```
'Default
Range("I2").Formula = "=+SUMIFS(R2C2:R434C2,R2C1:R434C1,RC[-1],R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"

'Option 1
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("B2:B434")
    Range("I2").Formula = _
        "=+SUMIFS(" & MyRange & ",R2C1:R434C1,RC[-1],R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"

'Option 2
    Range("I2").Formula = _
        "=+SUMIFS($B$2:$b$434,R2C1:R434C1,RC[-1],R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"
```

Comment: The answer by @user3598756 shows the correct syntax to use.  (Notice that option 2 is the same as your default one, but correctly using the `FormulaR1C1` property instead of forcing Excel to failover to it.)  Your option 2 wasn't working (I think) because you were trying to mix referencing methods within the one formula.

Answer (score 4):

```
'Default

Range("I2").Formula = "=+SUMIFS(R2C2:R434C2,R2C1:R434C1,RC[-1],R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"

'Option 1

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("B2:B434")
Range("I2").FormulaR1C1= _
    "=+SUMIFS(" & MyRange.Address(False,False,xlR1C1) & ",R2C1:R434C1,RC[-1],R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"

'Option 2

Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=+SUMIFS(R2C2:R434C2,R2C1:R434C1,RC[-1],R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"
```

Comment: @YowE3K I tried the option 1 but applying one more range. But it does not work for me.

Comment: `Option 1
    Dim irow As Long
    irow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("No Number", Range("A:A"), 0) - 2
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim haha As String
    haha = "B2:B" & irow + 1
    Set MyRange = Range(haha)
    
    Dim MyRange1 As Range
    Dim haha1 As String
    haha1 = "A2:A" & irow + 1
    Set MyRange1 = Range(haha1)
    
    Range("I2").Formula = _
        "=+SUMIFS(" & MyRange.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & "," & MyRange1.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",R2C3:R434C3,""G"")"`

Comment: @koky - In the code in your comment, your `SUMIFS` seems to be in the format `SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria_range2,criteria2)`, i.e. you seem to be missing `criteria1`.  (And please use the `FormulaR1C1` property when using R1C1 style formula - it will reduce the risk of other problems in the future.)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for pointing out! So you mean for excel vba, it is advisable to use FormulaR1C1 for cell referencing. The normal excel referencing cannot be used in excel vba right.

Comment: @koky - If you are writing a formula in VBA using the normal notation, use the `.Formula` property.  If you are writing a formula in VBA using R1C1 notation, use the `.FormulaR1C1` property.  R1C1 notation **tends** to be easier within VBA (because it is so much easier to say `RC[-4]` than it is to calculate what the current row is, and what the column letter is that is 4 columns left of the current column) but it really depends on what you are doing.  (The important thing is, don't try to mix the two notations within one formula.  I've seen a lot of people having problems that way.)